# Effect of switching spikes (400ns duration) on capacitor rated voltage

Tags: power-supply, noise, maximum-ratings, switching-transients

I have a motor drive which uses 63V electrolytic capacitors, which are the part with lowest-rated voltage on the drive's DC link. I measured the switching spikes on the DC link voltage (carefully, with spring-ground lead rather than ground clip to minimize lead length) and found on the order of 5V spikes at the 20kHz switching frequency with 48Vdc nominal; they last on the order of 400-500ns.

Here's my question: how do these switching spikes affect the 63V capacitor rating? Are they fast enough that I can ignore them and can allow the DC average voltage to get up to 63V? Or do I need to factor in these spikes, along with appropriate engineering margin, meaning I should stop somewhere in the 53-58V range depending on my conservativeness?

(Note: this assumes I am comfortable operating up to the low-frequency 63V rating, which I may or may not choose to do. That's a different question; I'm asking whether I need to take the high-frequency spikes into account.)

[image]

---

Cornell Dubilier's [application guide](http://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/AEappGUIDE.pdf) states the following (subject to interpretation of course)

> Aluminum electrolytic capacitors can generally withstand
>   extreme overvoltage transients of limited energy. Application of
>   overvoltage more than about 50 V beyond the capacitor’s surge
>   voltage rating causes high leakage current and a constant- Percent Rated Voltage voltage operating mode quite like the reverse conduction of
>   a zener diode. The capacitor may fail short if the electrolyte
>   cannot take the voltage stress, but even if it can, this operating
>   mode cannot be maintained for long because hydrogen gas
>   is produced by the capacitor, and the pressure build up will
>   cause failure. However, special designs are available that use
>   the overvoltage, zener-clamping efect to successfully protect
>   equipment from overvoltage transients such as lightning strikes.
>
> Capacitors used as bus capacitors in large, high-voltage
>   capacitor banks are less capable of withstanding overvoltage
>   transients because the high energy and low source impedance
>   of the capacitor bank can prevent a momentary partial discharge
>   from self healing and cause it to become a runaway shortcircuit
>   failure. For high-voltage capacitor-bank applications use
>   capacitors proven for that use.

edit: The above voltage was measured across a terminal block (Phoenix-style) that connects directly to power planes; so does the capacitor. I have also measured directly across the capacitor itself at 24V --- had to tip up the board holding everything together by hand, press oscope lead and ground ring against capacitor terminals, so I'm being a bit cautious before trying this at 48V:

[image]

(Screenshots of Agilent MSOX3034A 350MHz using 500MHz 10:1 passive probe.)

Comment: How much current are you switching? What size are the caps?

Comment: This particular example uses a Panasonic ECA1JHG471 470uF 63V capacitor (physical size 12.5mm diameter, 20mm height). Current most likely in the 1.0 - 1.5A range but it is difficult to correlate it directly with these switching transients.

Comment: How much do you think a 470uF cap can charge up at 1.5A for 400 nano-seconds? I figure 1.25mV, You are not seeing what you think you are seeing.

Comment: There are high-frequency plane capacitances on the order of 500-1000pF, plus capacitance from MOSFETs. I never said this electrolytic capacitor was the *cause* of these spikes. (At such high frequencies the electrolytic cap ESR + ESL makes it look noncapacitive; the electrolytic cap is helping me over longer periods of time.)

Comment: That is not what I am saying. I am saying the voltage across the capacitor dielectric can not be changing that much. What you are seeing on the scope is outside the cap and does not violate the cap voltage, assuming you are not already at the cap max V.

Comment: Hmm. Why can't voltage spikes across the cap be due to capacitor ESL/ESR? The 2nd scope plot is directly contacting the cap terminals. I suppose it could be measurement issues, but I don't know what to ignore at this point.

Comment: Because across the wires coming out of the cap IS NOT across the capacitor plates. That is internal beyond the cap ESR  and inductance of the leads. The spikes are likely due to capacitive coupling through whatever you are switching with. That is all happening a lot faster than the cap as a whole can react.

Comment: Okay, so what you're saying is that the voltage on the *terminals* of the capacitor is not what counts for life/reliability purposes; instead it is the voltage on the internal *electrodes*. This is the kind of answer I was looking for. In other words, fast spikes on the terminals get filtered slightly (breakpoints around the SRF). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly, you have to temper what you see on the scope with what can realistically happen where it counts.

Answer (score 2):

Lifetime of aluminum electrolytic capacitors is generally specified as the time under certain conditions of applied **DC voltage, ripple current, and ambient and surface temperature.** under these worst case conditions the lifetime is expressed in hours (eg 1000h @90'C).  Thus derating these absolute maximum values leads to multiplier values of lifetime for each of these parameters.

The criteria  is defined by the capacitor’s electrical parameters has drifted out of some specified limit. The ESR is usually first to go, so as self heating temp. rises with ESR, soon the capacitor will either run so hot that it suddenly shorts out or that it ruptures its safety vent and begins to dry out and drift open circuit.  Another failure mode is reverse and over-voltage stress.

CDE uses the criteria for extending Life by Voltage ratio, Mv of applied dc/rated dc;
   Mv = 4.3 - 3.3 Vdc/Vr   ... [ref p2](http://www.cde.com/resources/technical-papers/reliability.pdf)

Thus using Vdc/Vr = 2/3 ratio leads to a lifetime multiplier of 2.1x  while using 0Vdc leads to a lifetime multiplier of 4.3x and full rated voltage = 1x

**The actual peak voltage at the cap terminals is what counts for breakdown voltage stress.** It must be measured direct across the cap. terminals.

I don't think the ripple voltage in your photo indicates much RMS ripple current so the stress factor for ripple current is low.

Comment: I'm not convinced those spikes are real, at least not across the capacitor.

Comment: Yes they could be from the inductance between the cap and point of measurement.

Comment: Yes they must be from the inductance between the cap and point of measurement. SRF of the pulse is somewhere between 10M and >20MHz from the resonance which is far too high for an E-cap

Comment: Measured across a terminal block that connects directly to the ground/power plane. Capacitor connects directly to ground/power plane. Of course there are series inductances in both but we're talking 2-3mm wire max.

Comment: See latest edits. The HF resonance is most likely due to plane capacitance or MOSFET drain-source capacitance; this board designer did not put any ceramic caps across the half-bridges, which pisses me off.

Comment: @JasonS that means very little, it could also simply be noise pickup in the scope probe. I would be very surprised if the capacitor voltage can flip and oscillate like that. You did not answer my question on post yet...

Comment: FWIW I did measure scope ground with ground ring spring clip (no ground lead) connected to DC link negative, during drive operation, and it was quiet (noise level under 100mV; I forget the exact amount but it was small enough compared to the switching spike measurements that I ignored it). So I have some (not 100%) confidence that it is real voltages rather than radiated/conducted EMI.

Comment: @JasonS I think the Ecap is not under load here. It's ripple current would be related to motor commutation frequency. This is parasitic resonance and due to high ESR on supply cap.  ESR*C on E-cap is most likely 2~200us range from best to worst and never 0.1 to 0.5us. This can only be done by plastics, FR4 and ceramics

Comment: I'm not surprised; this whole issue would be likely be moot if there were ceramic caps across the half-bridges.

Comment: Half bridges usually have ultra low ESR E-caps near driver V+/-

Comment: really not appropriate to rely on electrolytics for that purpose -- https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/588.php

Comment: Yes they are.... e-caps must have SRF > f commutation rate of BLDC or stepper and ESR << DCR of motor. They supply the commutation transient current faster than the SMPS can regulate.  Then ceramic or plastic caps can improve Cap rating voltage margin reduced by parasitic spikes on the e-caps as needed in your case.

Comment: Tony, is it the voltage at the capacitor *terminals*, or at the interior *electrodes* that affects voltage rating? In other words, if these are fast transients with much of the spike voltage across the parasitic inductance of the capacitor leads, does it count against the voltage rating?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard anyone recommend running electrolytic capacitors exactly at their rated voltage. If you want to run at 63V, I would recommend replacing the caps. A 20% margin over the highest voltage you expect is probably safe.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking about the DC (low frequency) voltage rating; the capacitor manufacturer gives certain assurances, and whether I choose to go to 100% or 90% or 50% is another matter. I'm asking whether the capacitor "sees" such short spikes, or whether they are too short to have any effect. I know that power semiconductors will definitely see the short spikes and they have to be taken into account when determining voltage rating.

Comment: @JasonS sure you can use it to 100%, assuming you can guarantee you do not go over by a fraction of a percent. Good design practice is ALWAYS to de-rate parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your spikes have 20 nanosecond Trise. Across 10nanoHenry ESL. With deltaV of 2 volts.

V = L * dI/dT

dI = dT * V /L

dI = 20nS * 2v / 10nS = 4 amps.....................sounds about right?

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

How do you measure? That looks like an artifact caused by switching and poor CMRR of long ground leaded probe. If you use a very short ground lead (like 1cm),probably you will see nothing.

To support the point: it can be clearly seen that there are three- four dominant frequencies, meaning transfer function of switching to probe is a complex one. It involves ground lead inductance, area of the mesh by probe and it's lead, and so on. Cancel all those, picture will be much clearer and you will be much calmer.

Comment: This is better as a comment, not an answer. Also I took the probe hood off with no alligator ground clip. The first scope plot was with a short (approx 1cm) spring clip placed on the ground ring of the scope probe (sorry I don't have a picture) and contacting the power and ground plane through the top screws of a terminal block (approx 1cm to planes). The 2nd scope plot was with the spring clip removed and the probe tip and ground ring pressed directly to the capacitor terminals.